# how to add youtube 360 metadata by script

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata

I am working on a project which is about making 360 video on website then upload to youtube,
How do i add metadata to my video for recognise 360 by youtube?
I want do it by script, (ffmpeg php) for example.

Comment: I have found some one did it by Pyton   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z8VlD2rtACA    but I don't know Pyton, Can anyone show me how to make that by ffmpeg please

Comment: also this link might be useful  https://github.com/google/spatial-media/tree/master/spatialmedia